# Can a collision of 2 objects result in one object having a higher velocity than either object had before they collided?

Tags: kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws, velocity, collision

Assume I had 2 perfectly elastic billiards balls of the same size and mass, that can roll on an endless billiards table losing no kinetic energy to friction.

Is there a set of 2 velocities v1 and v2 (rate and direction) and start time and start position such that the balls collide and the result is that either one of the ball's velocities is greater than v1 and greater than v2?

Same question if the balls were differing masses?

Comment: have a look at this http://www.nj.com/news/index.ssf/2015/07/summer_fun_how_to_transfer_momentum_from_a_basketb.html and this http://physics.wfu.edu/demolabs/demos/avimov/bychptr/chptr3_energy.htm

Comment: Hint:  Solve this in a frame where one of the balls has initial velocity zero, and the other ball comes along the $x$ axis.

Comment: Well what I was really wondering was can a bunch of slow moving billiards balls all collide such that one of them get propelled away at a higher velocity than any of them had had before they collided?  I.e. can the opposite of a break shot be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a set of 2 velocities v1 and v2 (rate and direction) and
>   start time and start position such that the balls collide and the
>   result is that either one of the ball's velocities is greater than v1
>   and greater than v2?

For a single pair of equal mass objects, the answer is no.

If we look at a collision of two masses in the frame where their center of mass is at rest, each ball will depart with the same speed (or less) that it arrived with.

If we look at the collision in any other frame, then any boost we give to one of the outgoing objects simultaneously boosts the other incoming object.  So you can't increase the speed that way.

But if the objects have unequal mass (or you have more than two so that a couple can "gang up" on another), then it's no problem.  View the collision in a frame where the center of mass is moving toward the lighter mass (as an example, one where the lighter mass is at rest).  In that frame, the lighter mass will leave with greater speed than the heavier mass arrived with.

> Well what I was really wondering was can a bunch of slow moving
>   billiards balls all collide such that one of them get propelled away
>   at a higher velocity than any of them had had before they collided?
>   I.e. can the opposite of a break shot be done?

Well, that specific example is difficult to control.  It's theoretically possible, yes.  Just dramatically unlikely.  It's just a special case of the first example where you have a heavy mass object (in this case all the balls in the rack) striking a lower mass object (the cue ball).

Something not quite the same, but similar is the case where you drop multiple balls on the ground in a vertical line.  If you arrange them by mass, then you can get the top ball to rebound much higher/faster than any of them began with.

A video of this effect is visible at [Stacked Ball Drop YouTube](https://youtu.be/2UHS883_P60)

> The resulting velocity may only be <= the closing velocity of the 2
>   objects that collided.

If you can pick an arbitrary frame, then this is incorrect.  Let's expand on the train vs. tennis ball example.  In this case the train is so much more massive than the tennis ball, we can assume the center of mass to be the train.  In the frame of the train, the ball will rebound with the same speed that it impacted.

So let's imagine the train is approaching you at 30m/s and you throw a tennis ball at it at 10m/s.  This is a closing speed of 40m/s.  In the frame of the train, the ball approaches at 40m/s, then departs at 40m/s.  In your frame on the platform, the ball is thrown at 10m/s and rebounds back to you at 70m/s.  So the speed of the ball is faster (in your frame) than the closing speed of 40m/s.

> BowlOfRed, if your answer were correct then I could throw a bouncy
>   ball at a wall and it would deflect at a greater velocity than I've
>   thrown it.

That would be difficult because most of the time you are standing still and therefore (nearly) at rest with the center of mass.  What I said earlier was that to make it happen, the center of mass had to be moving toward the collision.  If the wall isn't moving, then that condition is not true.

Comment: "View the collision in a frame where the center of mass is moving toward the lighter mass (as an example, one where the lighter mass is at rest). In that frame, the lighter mass will leave with greater speed than the heavier mass arrived with."  So you're saying that mass A can propel lighter mass B faster than mass A is moving.  I.e. a train can push a car faster than the train  itself is traveling?

Comment: Trains and cars aren't very elastic.  But yes.  Maybe use a bouncy ball instead.  Throw a ball at a train moving toward you at 30m/s and it can leave at faster than 60m/s (relative to you).

Comment: Reflecting on all these answers, comments and suggestions, I've come up with what I think may be the answer to my own question. The resulting velocity may only be <= the closing velocity of the 2 objects that collided.  I.e. take the reference frame where object A is standing still and assume that object B propelled object A at the the same velocity as object B was traveling.  BowlOfRed, if your answer were correct then I could throw a bouncy ball at a wall and it would deflect at a greater velocity than I've thrown it. But the vertical bouncy ball experiment seems to contract what I'm saying.

Comment: @JoeC, added some responses to your comments in the answer.

Comment: Counterpoint: if you have a gas of billiard balls starting with all velocity v, it will thermalize to a boltzmann distribution, with high probability of some particle having much higher velocity than any individual started with. So it's generically really likely. Definitely not "opposite of a break shot" perfection, but similar.

Comment: @BowlOfRed, you are correct.  If I stood over the train on a bridge and simply dropped a tennis ball as the train approached at 30 m/s, then from the train's frame the ball approaches at 30 m/s then departs at 30 m/s.  But 30 m/s from the approaching train's frame is 60m/s from my frame on the bridge.  Does this mean that if you drop and hit a baseball it departs at twice the velocity of the part of the baseball that hit it?

Comment: Maybe not twice as fast (because the bat will be slowed down more than the train will), but otherwise yes.  If we consider the bat to be much more massive than the ball, then the ball will rebound at a speed around twice that of the bat.

Comment: Yeah the bat is being held a pushed by the batter.  The batter could be 250lb swiveling his hips and shoulders into the swing so I was pretending the bat lost negligible momentum.  
Out of curiosity, how many people who finished 2 or 3 semesters of physics (say B or better), would think the ball departs at the same velocity that the bat was moving?

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing I want to make you consider is that Velocities are not additives.
2. When a matter collides there is a transfer of **momentum** collectively and not the velocity as a single component.
3. If a heavy mass strike a smaller mass then the collective momentum increases but collective velocity decreases.
4. It is evident from the Newton's momentum equation 
   M1V1=M2V2

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.